# How can I get information about the user using a token

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, websocket

There is a need to receive user data using a token. Hello. There is a need to receive user data using a token. I have a web api + websockets, websockets connection via a web browser.

```
var webSocket = new WebSocket(handlerUrl);
//Open connection  handler.
webSocket.onopen = function () {
   webSocket.send("{\"type\":\"LOGIN\",\"access_token\":\"Bearer HIDDEN\"}");
};
```

Once connected, I immediately send token.
On the server side, it looks as follows:

```
 public class SocketClientController: ApiController
 {
     public HttpResponseMessage Get ()
     {
        HttpContext.Current.AcceptWebSocketRequest (new WebSocketHandler ());
        return Request.CreateResponse (HttpStatusCode.SwitchingProtocols);
     }
 <miss>
```

Socket class:

```
    <miss>
     private void Login(string access_token)
     {
// here i want get user info
     }

     public override void OnMessage(string input)
     {
           dynamic data = JObject.Parse(input);

           switch ((string)data.type)
           {
              case "LOGIN":
                Login((string)data.access_token);
              break;
           }
     }
```

I use Identity, a variant with a token when you first received from the client suits me the data. Tell me how you can get the user input without going through the login and password, and use [Authorize].

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Where do you save the token? You must save the tokens (like session-data) to validate the token you get from the user (login)

Comment: @rbr94 Thanks for the answer! I do not quite understand, this is not a problem to maintain a token in the Session, as it is possible to obtain a user name only a token?

Comment: You mean to combine both username and token, i.e. there is some kind of connection between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided my task! Below is the code:

```
  public class MachineKeyProtector : Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataProtection.IDataProtector
        {
            private readonly string[] _purpose =
            {
                    typeof(OAuthAuthorizationServerMiddleware).Namespace,
                    "Access_Token",
                    "v1"
                };

            public byte[] Protect(byte[] userData)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public byte[] Unprotect(byte[] protectedData)
            {
                return System.Web.Security.MachineKey.Unprotect(protectedData, _purpose);
            }
        }
```

Use:

```
 var secureDataFormat = new TicketDataFormat(new Providers.MachineKeyProtector());
 AuthenticationTicket ticket = secureDataFormat.Unprotect(access_token);
 var userId = ticket.Identity.GetUserId();
```